How to run gradle task written in Kotlin before compile?
I've created a simple plugin, it looks like that:
open class CodeGeneratorPlugin: Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.tasks.create("simpleCodeGenerator", CodeGeneratorTask::class.java).run {
            description = "Test"
            group = "CodeGeneratorTask"
            project.tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java){ dependsOn(it) }
        }
    }
}

My intention was to create a task that is strongly dependand to compile kotlin task, but line project.tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java){ dependsOn(it) } simply does not work. I'm running gradle clean build and It does not generate any code before build, compileKotlin is running instead.
How can I add dependency in task in plugin that will be automatically started when build is called? I want to add dependency to KotlinCompile task or build task in Kotlin class.

try this:
open class CodeGeneratorPlugin: Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        val simpleCodeGenerator = project.tasks.create("simpleCodeGenerator", CodeGeneratorTask::class.java).apply {
            description = "Test"
            group = "CodeGeneratorTask"
        }

        project.tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java).configureEach {
            dependsOn(simpleCodeGenerator)
        }
    }
}


Well, I think it's better, because now I've got KotlinSourceSet with name 'simpleCodeGenerator' not found. I see that It runs as first task.

did you add the sourceSets in your build.gradle? (and also, are you using kotlin DSL?)

I've got only sourceSets { main { kotlin { setSrcDirs(listOf("src/main/kotlin")) } } }  but I can't find any information about it. Why this sourceSet is named by my task?

This is my fault, now I found out what's the problem. Many thanks.

might be worth to add some description what was the fail, for future devs

continued at https://stackoverflow.com/q/78317645/4360272
