Running gradle task in Kotlin from another
I need to understand how can I properly register tasks in task and add dependency. For example, that's my task:
open class CodeGeneratorTask: DefaultTask() {

    @TaskAction
    fun action() {
        project.extensions.findByType(GenerationConfiguration::class.java)!!.let {
            it.contracts.forEach { contract ->
                createContractFileTask(project.tasks, contract) //creates tasks named contract.downloadTaskName
                project.tasks.register(contract.generateTaskName, GenerateTask::class.java, generateClasses(contract))
                project.tasks.named(contract.generateTaskName) { dependsOn(contract.downloadTaskName) }
                project.tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java) { dependsOn(project.tasks.named(contract.downloadTaskName)) }
                project.extensions.getByType(KotlinJvmProjectExtension::class.java).sourceSets.getByName("main").kotlin
                    .srcDir(project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated/${contract.path}/src/main/kotlin").get())
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

I need to register two kind of tasks: one that downloads file, another generates code from downloaded file. It's necessary to run those tasks before kotlinCompile task. I can not run this due to "Cannot call Task.dependsOn(Object...) on task ':simpleCodeGenerator' after task has started execution.". Now I'm stuck because I don't know how to add this dependency. CodeGeneratorTask is running before KotlinCompile.

Using dependsOn
dependsOn can be used to chain tasks, but you need to call that during the project's configuration phase, not its execution phase as you are doing here. Take a look at the explanation of the Gradle project lifecycle.
So you could write, in the build.gradle.kts:
tasks {
    val codeGeneratorTask = register<CodeGeneratorTask>("generateCode") {
        // configure codeGeneratorTask
    }
    withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
        dependsOn(codeGeneratorTask)
    }
}

All of the above code runs (to the extent it runs) in the configuration phase. It is the actions of the tasks that run during the execution phase, when it is too late to tell Gradle which tasks depend on which others.
Using inputs and outputs
That will work, but it isn't really the right way to do it. The right way is to give each task inputs and outputs (docs).
In Gradle, tasks are assigned inputs and outputs, and then Gradle deduces task dependencies, so that if Task A's output is used by Task B as an input, Task B is made to depend on Task A.
If you dig deeply enough into the code of the Kotlin plugin, you'll discover that inputs to the Kotlin compile tasks are, as we'd expect, the files that make up the Kotlin source. So, actually a better way getting the Kotlin compile task to depend on the output of a given task, is to include that task's output in the Kotlin source.
To do this, we must give our task an output:
open class CodeGeneratorTask: DefaultTask() {

    @OutputDirectory
    val outputDir: DirectoryProperty = project.objects.directoryProperty().convention(
        project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("myGeneratedCode")
    )

}

Obviously make sure the @TaskAction function puts code in this directory!
Now we have a directory we can add to the Kotlin source (assuming JVM plugin here):
tasks {
    val codeGeneratorTask = register<CodeGeneratorTask>("generateCode") {
        // configure codeGeneratorTask
    }
        // We use the map function to access the directory lazily
    kotlin.sourceSets.main.get().kotlin.srcDirs(codeGeneratorTask.map { it.outputDir })
}

To check this has worked, run ./gradlew compileKotlin --dry-run and it should show the task generateCode as running before compileKotlin.
You can do the same chaining with your own inputs by defining inputs using the @InputFile or @InputFiles annotations, then assigning outputs from other tasks to them during the configuration phase.

It's awesome, thanks! So, in my case, I have to register tasks in configuration phase and add dependency... I'll try it, many thanks for big explanation!
